The slide out animation doesn't work properly, it triggers when I refresh the page
I'm having an annoying problem that I can't solve, I'm controlling a modal that is controlled through a basically true/false state, its works fine, but when i refresh the page the slideout animation triggers by itself because the state is false, what can I do to avoid this?
Ive tried  this display: ${({ error }) => error ? 'flex' : 'none'};  
but if I do so, the slideOut animation does not work only the slideIn.
My component:
const ErrorContent = ({ message, error }: ResponseErrorInterface) => {
  return (
    <StyledErrorContent error={error}>
      <img src={ErrorSvg} alt={'error-response'} />
      <span className={'modalMessage'}>{message}</span>
    </StyledErrorContent>
  );
};

styled-component:
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import ResponseErrorInterface from '../../../../commons/model/interfaces/ResponseErrorInterface';

const slideIn = keyframes`
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-262px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
`;

const slideOut = keyframes`
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: .5;
        transform: translateX(-262px);
    }
`;

const StyledErrorContent = styled.div<Pick<ResponseErrorInterface, 'error'>>`
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 262px;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background.modalErrorBackground};
    border-bottom-right-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.radius.medium};
    border-top-right-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.radius.medium};
    margin-left: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    gap: 20px;
    animation: ${({ error }) => error ? slideIn : slideOut} 300ms ease-out forwards;

span.modalMessage {
    width: 140px;
    font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.height.regular};
    font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.size.xLarge};
    line-height: 130%;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-align: center;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background.modalErrorText};
}
`;

StyledErrorContent.shouldForwardProp = (prop) => prop !== 'error';

export default StyledErrorContent;

